# Sort images in grid based on user input

Tags: image, image-processing, google-sheets, computer-vision, data-visualization

I have a few hundred images that I would like to have a user manually sort along two axes.  Each row represents a users perceived nominal label, eg red, orange, yellow, green, ... The images in a row are ordered according to some feature perceived by the user (eg brightness).  So given an image the person sorting should be able to determine which row it belongs to and which two images it should be between in the row and insert it there.

Initially I tried using Google sheets and loading the images into cells in the spreadsheet.  The problem I encountered are the images are really low resolution and Google sheets applies some blending to the pixels (eg linear?, bicubic?) which made understanding the images too difficult for my user.  If I could load an image and have it resize using the nearest pixel color I think it would be fine.

I have looked at some photo organizing software, the closest feature I can find is organizing photos based on geo-coordinates onto a 2D map, which isn't intuitive for my user.

I suppose I could create a webapp that the user could assign a row and column too, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

The intent is to apply machine learning on the provided labels so that we can automatically sort larger datasets, so it would be great if the solution could be used with machine provided metadata, which could then be visually inspected for accuracy.

Comment: what is the question? do you need someone to implement a GUI that allows a user to put a set of pictures in some order?

Comment: Yes, I need to implement a GUI to order images similar to how you can order things in a spreadsheet.

Comment: If there is already existing software to do this I am happier to use an off the shelf solution.